# Predual of $W^*$-subalgebra

Tags: operator-algebras, quotient-spaces, von-neumann-algebras, dual-spaces

I've seen many references claiming that if $\mathcal{N}$ is a $\sigma$-weakly closed *-subalgebra of a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{M}$, then by taking $\mathcal{N}_\bot:=\{\phi\in\mathcal{M}_*|a(\phi)=0\text{ for all }a\text{ in }\mathcal{M}\}$ we have $\left(\mathcal{M}_*/\mathcal{N}_\bot\right)^*=\mathcal{N}$ (see e.g. Sakai, 1998). I would like to see a proof of this fact. Any references or inline proofs are much appreciated! I have the vague idea that it has to do with the general result $(V/W)^*=W^\bot$ where $V$ is a vector space, $W$ is a subspace and $W^\bot$ its annihilator.

I am interested in this fact because, since the uniform topology is finer that the $\sigma$-weak one, it proves that $\mathcal{N}$ is a $W^*$-algebra.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe I've found most of the proof already. Indeed $\left(\mathcal{M}_*)/\mathcal{N}_\bot\right)^*=(\mathcal{N}_\bot)^\bot$ as proved here http://www.math.tamu.edu/~schlump/lecture7and8.pdf. It is clear that $\mathcal{N}\subseteq(\mathcal{N}_\bot)^\bot$. I am missing the other implication which should depend on a result like: the $\sigma$-weak closure of a *-subalgebra $\mathcal{N}$  of a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{M}$ coincides with $(\mathcal{N}_\bot)^\bot$.

Comment: Found the solution in https://math.la.asu.edu/~quigg/teach/courses/578/2008/notes/adjoints.pdf